# CSS Floats not going as planned

Tags: css, css-float

So I'm pretty new to both css and html but this is not the first time that I have used floats to achieve 2 divs sitting next to each other. This time it is not working properly and I've been tinkering around for about 3 hours and I figure I should call on some help.

I have edited the portion of my website in jsFiddle to assist in describing my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/9QRcP/10/

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is meant to be where

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't that you're not assigning your `div`s to `float: right`, but that your `div`s are small enough that you can fit multiple of them within the page width, so they're doing exactly what they should do.

To fix this, though, [we would add `clear:right`](http://jsfiddle.net/9QRcP/16/) to `#about_side` and `#about_side_footer`, **but that won't force them to be level**, so it doesn't quite fix the problem.

To fix that problem as well, instead of floating each individual piece of your `#greeting_wrapper` and `#about_wrapper` left and right, respectively, [float the wrappers left and right instead](http://jsfiddle.net/9QRcP/18/).

```
#greeting_wrapper {
  float: left;
}

#about_wrapper {
  float: right;
}

#greeting_header, #greeting, #greeting_footer, #about_side_header, #about_side, #about_side_footer {
  float: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nightfirecat. I added those wrappers at some point in my troubleshooting and I never made use of them! Guess I should take more frequent breaks and save myself the embarrassment!

Answer (score 1):

I found that you need to float `#greeting_wrapper` and `#about_wrapper`. These wrappers are the important elements. As far as I can tell, the children of these `div`s shouldn't need to be floated as well.

Also currently those `div`s are taking on the width of the body which is 960px thus forcing both `div`s onto a new line.

Answer (score 0):

I had a fiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/9QRcP/15/

I haven't bothered to correct the alignment, but left is now on left and right is now on right.

By my own admission this isn't a very good approach to this. A few pointers:

1. you can use 'clear: left' to force an element on the left to move to a new line http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp
2. you should probably contain your left and right elements in 2 seperate containers (e.g. class="container left" and class="container-right" ). Clear left for any sub-element in the left container that you want to move to the next vertical level, and likewise for elements in the right container. This will allow you to easily break your page up into columns. Here 's one I prepared earlier http://jsfiddle.net/9QRcP/19/ from http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html
3. you could probably save yourself a lot of work by using a grid system, e.g. http://960.gs/

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html - better? Actually, this is a good discussion of the problem at hand. I still think breaking the page into left and right container divs would be the most manageable solution. I have updated my answer to include a fiddle demo of this.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with the width of your wrapper. If you increase the width, the floated div will take its place on the right.

Comment: @Nightfirecat try div id="about_wrapper" style="width:2000px;" and you'll see. Is it the reason for the downvote?

Comment: Do you mean to write [`#about_wrapper{width:2000px;}` in the CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/9QRcP/20/)? That also doesn't work. (and yes, that's why I downvoted)

Comment: That's exactly what I am talking about and it works on your jsfiddle. I just tried in IE and Chrome, and the div that says "I should be over to the right!" has moved to the right compared to the initial example.

Comment: [I'm seeing this kind of effect in both Firefox and Chrome](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PkZNz.png), when I think what the OP meant was to make the right set of `div`s look more like the left set: stacked up, and in line with its counterpart.